# Is it possible to sort things by categorized columns in isotope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'd like to sort things in a format similar to the following...

```
-----------------------
| cat1 | dog1 | bird1 |
-----------------------
| cat2 | dog2 | bird2 |
-----------------------
| cat3 | dog3 | 
---------------
       | dog4 |
       --------
```

Is it possible to sort this way?

I understand it's possible to do a linear column sort similar to this:

```
----------------------
| cat1 | cat4 | cat7 |
----------------------
| cat2 | cat5 | cat8 |
----------------------
| cat3 | cat6 | 
---------------
```

But I need it to sort by category. Is it possible to do this in isotope and if so can you provide an example?

Also can it sort in two (or more) different ways simultaneously like this?

(Notice the cats are sorted vertically while the dogs are sorted horizontally.)

```
----------------------
| cat1 | cat4 | cat7 |
----------------------
| cat2 | cat5 | cat8 |
----------------------
| cat3 | cat6 | 
----------------------
| dog1 | dog2 | dog3 |
----------------------
| dog4 | dog5 | dog6 |
----------------------
| dog7 |
--------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Isotop doesn't supoort your requests by current version (v2.1.0) but You can  add Null element ( like a empty div with height and width ) in the categories and show / hide them according by your needs for example for displaying this order

```
-----------------------
| cat1 | dog1 | bird1 |
-----------------------
| cat2 | dog2 | bird2 |
-----------------------
| cat3 | dog3 | 
---------------
       | dog4 |
       --------
```

you can add a null element and show at last row of items as below and choose `cellsByColumn` for its layout. Null elements doesn't have anything in content and style . They only fill spaces by their height / width.

```
-----------------------
| cat1 | dog1 | bird1 |
-----------------------
| cat2 | dog2 | bird2 |
-----------------------
| cat3 | dog3 | 
---------------
| Null | dog4 |
---------------
```

for achieving another structure, you can add another Null element at third column's point and choose normal layout.

```
----------------------
| cat1 | cat4 | cat7 |
----------------------
| cat2 | cat5 | cat8 |
----------------------
| cat3 | cat6 | Null |
----------------------
| dog1 | dog2 | dog3 |
----------------------
| dog4 | dog5 | dog6 |
----------------------
| dog7 |
--------
```

Check out my codes for [sample1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvEjPb) and [sample2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myreRv).

Comment: Notice for the second question the cats are sorted vertically while the dogs are sorted horizontally.

Comment: @rotaercz yes i know.i just gave an idea of how you can do it.you can achieve that with some normal sort types.

Comment: @rotaercz i have edited my answer and added my codes.i hope to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of similar requirement

i have used this

```
function sortBy(tag) {


    $('.isotope-item').each(function(index, value) 
    {
        var arrayOfCategories = $(this).attr('data-category').split(" ");

        for (var i=0; i < arrayOfCategories.length; i++){

          if((tag.indexOf(arrayOfCategories[i]) !== -1)) {
            //console.log('match');
            $(this).attr('data-sort-order', 1);
            break;
          } else {
            //console.log('no match');
            $(this).attr('data-sort-order', 2);
          }    
        }

    });

    $container.isotope( 'updateSortData', $('.isotope-item'));
    //$container.isotope( 'reLayout' );
    $container.isotope({ sortBy : 'sortOrder' });    
  }
```

and i am setting "data-sort-order" attribute for some category items, By passing the "data-sort-order" value to the function will sort the elements which has this properties.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of what you're doing?